# No Service Provider available in ValidationContext

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, blazor, blazor-server-side

I am using the built in form validation in Blazor with data annotations. Now I have a validation where I need my EFCore Context and discovered, that DI is available in `ValidationAttribute`s via `ValidationContext` ([Source](https://github.com/dotnet/AspNetCore.Docs/issues/26457)).

At first I tried to directly inject my EFCore Context like that:

```cs
public class MyEntityExistsAttribute : ValidationAttribute
{
    protected override ValidationResult IsValid(object value, 
        ValidationContext validationContext)
    {
        if (value is not int id)
        {
            return new ValidationResult("The ID is not a number");
        }
        
        var context = validationContext.GetRequiredService<IMyContext>();

        if (context.MyEntity.Any(s => s.Id == id))
        {
            return ValidationResult.Success;    
        }
        return new ValidationResult("The ID does not exist.");
    }
}
```

As that did not work with the following exception: `System.InvalidOperationException: No service for type 'MyApp.Model.IMyContext' has been registered.`

I tried it with creating my own scope:

```cs
public class MyEntityExistsAttribute: ValidationAttribute
{
    protected override ValidationResult IsValid(object value, 
        ValidationContext validationContext)
    {
        if (value is not int id)
        {
            return new ValidationResult("The ID is not a number");
        }

        using var scope = validationContext.CreateScope();
        var context = scope.ServiceProvider.GetRequiredService<IMyContext>();

        if (context.MyEntity.Any(s => s.Id == id))
        {
            return ValidationResult.Success;    
        }
        return new ValidationResult("The ID does not exist.");
    }
}
```

But now it already crashes when trying to create the scope:
`System.InvalidOperationException: No service for type 'Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.IServiceScopeFactory' has been registered.`

I also tried this pattern already:

```cs
var context = (IMyContext) validationContext
     .GetService(typeof(IMyContext));
```

But this results in the context being `null`.

Comment: Hi,@Patrick,you should avoid injecting service into Attribute,and here's a similar issue，hopes help:https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62559817/how-to-get-inject-services-in-custom-validationattributes

Answer (score 0):

Your code should work in .net 7

[image]

Test result in .net 6

[image]

Like you see, my project is in .net 7 and libraries are version 7 but not 6

[image]

Comment: That's what I read, too. But I am on .NET 7 with all my projects in the solution (I have one Blazor Server app as project and multiple class libraries, which also are all on .NET 7). Is there any other place to set the .NET version?

Comment: Hi, I think we could check the project file and upgrading to .net 7, including the nuget packages, upgrade all of them to .net  7 corresponding version and rebuild the application.